# How to make the software updater application scan for updates and notify the user of the option to update?

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

I'm trying to have an apt repository mirror that gets updated periodically in an air-gapped lab network. I want the Software Updater application to scan for updates and present the logged in user with the notice and option to update. I'm looking for a solution that applies to 20.04 or 22.04.

I've found some info by searching the dconf-editor but I haven't yet found any good documentation.

I'm just not sure exactly why this isn't working right now and figured I'd go digging to see what I could find in terms of logs or config files.

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking. It seems like you're asking how to make the software center scan for updates and prompt the user to update when updates are available. It already does that. Can you provide a clearer description of what you want?

Comment: Try the command `update-manager`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Update Manager and apt cannot update sources and package info if you have no Internet.  Of interest might be this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/649476/how-to-get-the-updating-list-and-import-to-my-offline-computer

Comment: @Nmath - Sure.  The Ubuntu system (running 20.04.4) and Apt mirror are both in an air gapped network.  The Ubuntu system has had its /etc/apt/source.list file modified so that it can retrieve both updates and install new packages without any issue.  Something I've noticed is that when I compare it to a system that has Internet access, the update-manger appears to run upon user login to GDM.

This isn't working and I suspect that the update manager is trying to do some base check like connect to security.ubuntu.com or something like that but because that's failing it fails to continue on.

Comment: @ThomasWard - Thanks for this.  I'll take a peek and see if this leads anywhere.

Comment: @user535733 - Yep... thats the app.  I don't suppose you know where any of the configurations for this app are held do you?